# Necessary to release subviews in ARC?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

If one creates in XCode, a UIViewController using ARC, the `viewDidUnload:` method is defined as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}
```

If one then creates a button in the XIB, this code is inserted automatically at the top of the method:

```
[self setSomeButton:nil];
```

Is any of this code necessary at all with ARC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not affected by ARC. You still have to set your strong IBOutlets to nil.

It is affected by iOS 6, though. But that's under NDA, for now.

Comment: Can you explain - why do we still have to set strong IBOutlets to nil? (And only IBOutlets but not non-XIB views?)

Comment: Of course you still have to release all views in ivars, properties and wherever you hold strong references to them. The reason is that ARC just releases objects automatically when there are no more strong references. Since the view controller will still be around, it has to give up its references.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to keep in mind that under most circumstances, `viewDidUnload` is never called. In my experience, it is only called when your VC is "above" the current VC in a navigation stack and is off-screen **and** there is a low-memory situation.

It is my understanding that Apple put that code there to *remind* you that your subviews *have gone away* in that case.

Note that they do not put that code in `dealloc`, since (as you rightly assumed) ARC *does* take care of cleanup for you (since these are usually *weak* pointers)

Comment: It's not a seldom case: Whenever your view is not on screen and memory gets tight.

Comment: Well, what I really mean is, "it's not part of the *default* view lifecycle". The details of how often it actually occurs are highly dependent on too many factors to make a singular characterization, I suppose.